# Access broccoli server from other device

Tags: broccolijs

I'm using broccoli to develop a simple app and I'm trying to access it from a mobile phone.
However, even if I'm able to access the site from my computer at localhost:42000 I'm not able to do so when I point the browser of my phone at 10.0.1.8:4200.

Is it possible to access the broccoli server from other devices? If not, how do you suggest me to handle this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, localhost is 127.0.0.1, which is not accessible from outside your computer by default, but... You can use a development proxy like [Pow](http://pow.cx/) to fix this.

Pow is very simple to setup and configure to your needs and apart from that awesomeness [it can serve your apps to other devices on the same network](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.1.5).

What you need to know before you proceed with the steps below:

1. Your computer's IP address on your LAN.
2. The name of your app.

For the example steps below let's use the following values.

1. IP: 10.0.1.8
2. App name: magicapp

Steps to happiness (if you run OS X or Linux):

1. Install Pow with: 
   `$ curl get.pow.cx | sh`
2. Tell Pow to look for your app at localhost port 4200 with:
   `echo 4200 > ~/.pow/magicapp`

Voilà. If all went well, you should be able to access your app from other devices on the same network at: `http://magicapp.10.0.1.8.xip.io/`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply launch the broccoli hosting server via

```
broccoli serve --host YOUR_IP --port YOUR_PORT
```